# How to know if all the cells have the same value in some column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, conditional-statements, equivalent

How to know if all the cells have the same value in some column (title changed)

I want to have a bit scalar value that tells me if all the values in a column equal something:

```
DECLARE @bit bit
SELECT @bit = TRUEFORALL(Name IS NOT NULL) FROM Contact
```

**UPDATE**

I now realized that I actually don't need the TrueForAll, what I do need is to make sure, that all values in a column are equal, for example, I want to know whether all Group.Items have the same price.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your updated requirement something like this would appear to do what you want:

```
DECLARE @IsSameGroup bit
SELECT @IsSameGroup = CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM (SELECT Name FROM Contact GROUP BY Name) groups
```

When the count is greater the 1 you have two different names (or prices depending on what you group on)

Comment: @Blorgbeard The subselect gives the count of the number of groups. Without that you just get multiple records (one per group). Horses for courses really.

Comment: Is not that more plain? DECLARE @IsSameGroup bit = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Contact GROUP BY [Name] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

Answer (score 20):

Why not?

```
select count( distinct price) from table
```

If returns 1, all values are the same...   Add

`where price is not null`

if need be

Comment: upvoted for count(distinct x), which seems to be the most obvious solution here to me (certainly the first one I thought of) and is also valid ANSI SQL 92, and so as cross-playform as you'll get.

Comment: Finally, a non-hacky use for `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: Exactly more clear solution than the marked one.

Answer (score 2):

Not very good for NULLs, but 2008 can do:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE 'Blue' = ALL ( SELECT Color FROM dbo.Hat )
```

OR

```
DECLARE @bit bit

SET @bit = 
CASE ( SELECT 1 WHERE 'Blue' = ALL ( SELECT Color FROM dbo.Hat ))
WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

**UPDATE**

All same color

```
SET @bit = 
CASE(
   SELECT 1 WHERE
  (SELECT TOP(1) Color FROM dbo.Hat) = ALL ( SELECT Color FROM dbo.Hat )
    )
WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
DECLARE @bit bit
if exists(SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE Name IS NULL) 
   SET @bit = 0
ELSE
  SET @bit = 1
```

Comment: Of course, this is the opposite of the logic expressed in the OP's question. It should be `WHERE Name IS NULL` and set the `bit` to 0, otherwise set it to 1.

Comment: Exists will return true if 1+ records satisfy the logic

Comment: I made a mistake in my question, please review it. thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This solves your first question:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM Contact
            WHERE Name IS NULL
        ) THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END
```

ADDED:

This will solve your second:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM (
                SELECT
                    ItemGroupName,
                    COUNT(Price) AS CNT
                FROM ItemGroup
                GROUP BY ItemGroupName
                HAVING COUNT(Price) > 1
            ) t
        ) THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END
```

By the way, when you use the exists function, its better to SELECT 1 (a constant) so less data gets returned